PowerShell Regex: Removing specific parts of a string based on patterns
I want to remove all parts of the string that I don't need, leaving only the name. I’m not getting the expected result. Instead of just "Aryshenskyi, Mihail", I’m getting an empty string. What am I doing wrong, and how can I modify my code to achieve the desired output?
$text = "CN=Aryshenskyi\, Mihail,OU=Users,OU=SMZ,DC=smzmi,DC=local"
$regex = "(CN=).+?(\\), .+?(,OU=.+)"
$result = $text -replace $regex, ""
Write-Host $result


You can adapt the regexes found in these answers with -replace to extract the common name then you can apply another replace for the backslash. See https://regex101.com/r/Clg5xj/1 for regex details.
$text = "CN=Aryshenskyi\, Mihail,OU=Users,OU=SMZ,DC=smzmi,DC=local"
$text -replace '^CN=|(?<!\\),.+' -replace '\\'

You could adapt the regex you currently have to make it work in a single replacement however this one only works for Distinguished Names having an escaped comma in their common name. It would also fail for users in a Container instead of in an OU. See https://regex101.com/r/46Xa2V/1 for regex details.
$text = "CN=Aryshenskyi\, Mihail,OU=Users,OU=SMZ,DC=smzmi,DC=local"
$text -replace '^CN=(.+?)(?:\\)(, .+?),OU=.+', '$1$2'

Adding another option that should handle the replacement on one go including removing the backslash escaping the comma in the common name. See https://regex101.com/r/YuGge3/1 for regex details.
$dns = @(
    'CN=Aryshenskyi\, Mihail,OU=Users,OU=SMZ,DC=smzmi,DC=local'
    'CN=Aryshenskyi Mihail,OU=Users,OU=SMZ,DC=smzmi,DC=local'
)

$dns -replace '^CN=|\\(?=,)|(?<!\\),.+'


But why my regex doesn't work? I checked regex101 site, It does captures "CN="; ""; ",OU=Users,OU=SMZ,DC=smzmi,DC=local". Why removing part is not working?

You're capturing the CN= and everything after OU= including it in capturing groups 1 and 2 instead of capturing what you're looking to extract @user2978216. see the update that is close to what you were up to

The pattern matches the whole string.  Putting back the last and first name, adding two more capture groups.  See regex101.com to test out expressions.  Select-string in powershell 7 highlights matches.

'CN=Aryshenskyi\, Mihail,OU=Users,OU=SMZ,DC=smzmi,DC=local' -replace 
  '(CN=)(.+?)(\\), (.+?)(,OU=.+)', '$2, $4'

Aryshenskyi, Mihail

You don't really need the other capture groups:
'CN=Aryshenskyi\, Mihail,OU=Users,OU=SMZ,DC=smzmi,DC=local' -replace
  'CN=(.+?)\\, (.+?),OU=.+', '$1, $2'

Aryshenskyi, Mihail

Or else use regex lookahead or lookbehind.  Or get the active directory GivenName and Surname properties instead, or DisplayName
